# Error in posting data through Axios to Django Rest Framework server,Error code 500

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I use token authentication to communicate between React and DRF. I can make GET request using below token but can not POST data to server with payload.

```
    axios.post('URL',
    {
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Token 83d1892877db7950c1c5a818cbb6ca738e53f90b'} 

})
      .then(function (response) {
       console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

I get error 500 from Django server when posting above.But with same URL and Token I could successfully execute POST request in Postman.

I want to add a data with the axios POST request, the data is {name:'myname'}.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headers should be the 3rd parameter in your call to `axios.post`, you are passing them as 2nd parameter which is the body.

```
axios.post(URL, data, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Token 83d1892877db7950c1c5a818cbb6ca738e53f90b'
  }
})
```